# Weird iMessage behavior on Yosemite

Tags: macos, messages

Something weird is happening with iMessage on my Mac. I can send and receive messages fine but when I close iMessage and reopen it, all my messages disappear. Also, if the app is closed and I get a message, I get a notification but when I open the app it's not there.

The conversations are all there but they are empty.

What I've tried so far:

1. Signed out of my account, closed iMessage and restarted the computer.
2. Deleted all plists related to iMessage in `~/Library/Preferences`
3. Delete `~/Library/IdentityServices`

What else should I try?

Comment: Try setting up the account again in a new user account as a test.

Comment: Since when did this behaviour occur? Did you recover from a TimeMachine backup? Have you tried do use Disk Utility to fix permissions?

Comment: No, I didn't recover from a TimeMachine backup or used Disk Utility.

Comment: I've created a new user account and tested it, it works fine. Now what? How can I get it to work in my account?

Comment: Do you have any other devices that are signed in to iMessage with the same Apple ID?

Comment: I am having the same issue since July 12. I was making some updates and downloading files larger than my disk space allowed. I briefly saw a pop-up telling me that it may affect the message database, but dismissed as I was deleting other files to make some space. Since then, no newer archives have been created. Re: tron_jones reply, I have tried the process, but even after restarting the Mac, i cannot empty the trash as the .db files seem to be in use :(

Comment: Yes, I do have an iPod Touch, an iPad and an iPhone all signed in using the same Apple ID with iMessage working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure the "Save history when conversations are closed" is checked in "Preferences-->General" to have an archive of conversations in the future.

Second the Messages.app history and archives are saved to a couple locations in Yosemite.

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/Data/Library/Messages/
~/Library/Messages/
```

Backup the files in the folder ~/Library/Messages/ and save to a separate location to have a backup of your previous messages.(if they exist)

Then remove both the files in above paths:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/Data/Library/Messages/*
rm -rf ~/Library/Messages
```

Restart Messages.app and the below message will appear that it is rebuilding your Messages database.  The couple times a have done this it resulted in having to just restart the machine as I didn't want to wait.

[image]

Just remember to make a backup of any files you delete as they hold archives of previous conversations.

Comment: Sadly that also didn't solve it. I returned to the same [empty conversations view](https://www.dropbox.com/s/23k5xaeumo5gdlu/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-22%20at%2010.06.27%20AM.png?dl=0). How is it retaining the conversations after all archives have been removed?

Comment: So for some reason I don't understand, iMessage started working again normally after my computer kernel panicked and restarted. I believe that clearing that archive followed by a restart was what it needed. I'm accepting your answer as it's _probably_ what fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*This assumes the storage in your user account is to blame, there could be other reasons.*

Log into the affected account. Ensure `Messages.app` is not running by quitting it from the `Messages` menu.

Activate `Finder`, select `Home` from the `Go` menu, select `Get Info` from the `File` menu. Click the disclosure triangle next to `Sharing & Permissions` if it isn't already pointing down.

Ensure the single head icon shows your account name and "`(me)`".

Unlock the box at the bottom right, then click the action button (looks like a gear) and choose `Apply to enclosed items`. When it warns that it can't be undone, click Ok.

Comment: I've tried doing that and the problem is still there. Thanks.